# Load balancer using apache2 not works in WSDL

Tags: apache, nginx, wsdl, load-balancing, internal-load-balancer

I am trying to load balance a request of a WSDL:

then I have configured my apache and Nginx to do it, and not works with any.

I have my apache configuration with:

```
<VirtualHost *:3332>
  <Proxy "balancer://mycluster">
    BalancerMember "https://localhost:5443"
    BalancerMember "https://localhost:5443"
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPass        "/ESBService" "balancer://mycluster"
  ProxyPassReverse "/ESBService" "balancer://mycluster"
</VirtualHost>
```

And I have changed my wsdl that works fine with

```
<wsdl:service name="Servname_HTTP_Service">
    <wsdl:port name="ServnameSOAP_HTTP_Port" binding="ns0:ServnameSOAP_HTTP_Binding">
      <soap11:address location="https://localhost:5443/contextpath/Servname"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

to:

```
<wsdl:service name="Servname_HTTP_Service">
    <wsdl:port name="ServnameSOAP_HTTP_Port" binding="ns0:ServnameSOAP_HTTP_Binding">
      <soap11:address location="http://localhost:3332/contextpath/Servname"/>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```

And i am getting:

```
org.apache.cxf.interceptor.Fault: Response was of unexpected text/html ContentType.  Incoming portion of HTML stream: <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">
<html><head>
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
</head><body>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error or
misconfiguration and was unable to complete
your request.</p>
<p>Please contact the server administrator at
 [no address given] to inform them of the time this error occurred,
 and the actions you performed just before this error.</p>
<p>More information about this error may be available
in the server error log.</p>
<hr>
<address>Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 3332</address>
</body></html>
```

And Using the tomcat, (changing https://localhost:5443 to http://localhost8080)

What is my error, or how can I do the load balance?

In this test I have the same IP localhost:5443, but the idea is that the IP change.

And with Nginx I have:

```
cd /etc/nginx/
```

Configuring nginx as a load balancer

```
sudo vi /etc/nginx/conf.d/load-balancer.conf
```

Define the following conten in the file:

```
upstream lbvalidsite {
server ec2-34-238-244-237.compute-1.amazonaws.com weight=3;
server ec2-54-144-235-129.compute-1.amazonaws.com;
}
server {
    listen 3332;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://lbvalidsite;
    }
}
```

And Load Balancing an Apache with my nginx works, but using my wsdl not works.

What is my problem?

I need the apache or the Nginx, one working no more.

Comment: If you are getting "connection refused", check if apache is configured to listen on port 3332 (`Listen 3332 https`).

Comment: do you have resolver defined somewhere in the nginx config?

Comment: as well? I only have the nginx.conf and my load-balancer.conf

Comment: Finally, it works, i am using this tutorial, the problem was the ssl connection:
https://serversforhackers.com/c/tcp-load-balancing-with-nginx-ssl-pass-thru